# How can I set a group of windows to focus when one is focused

Tags: window-manager, window-management

I'm looking for a WM or a method for Cinnamon which would allow me to focus a group of windows, bringing them to the front, when any one of them is focused. For example, I have an IDE with 3 windows (one editor, 2 tool panes) and I want them all to focus when any one of them are focused.

I'm currently using Cinnamon, but I am open to changing.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/805515/how-can-i-group-windows-to-be-raised-as-one